# Is it possible to load a separate application into the iphone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, jailbreak

I am having a iphone and i have created an application using Xcode. Now i want to move this application into my iphone for my use. How can it be done?

I tried to copy my application to the iphone Applications folder using the phone view software, but i'm not able to open my application in the iphone. It shows the error

> "Your Myapp.app cannot be open"

Is there any other way to install my application into the iphone? Please guide me regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to register as an iPhone developer to get the correct keys for signing and loading an application onto an iPhone. If you are writing an application that you plan to sell via the AppStore then this is $99 to register, if it's for internal use only then $199.

Comment: To clarify for the OP, if the application is use on his development iPhone, then the $99 cert is perfectly useable. The $199 cert allows installing on non-development iPhones within an organization.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered that the app would be for single use but on re-reading the question you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

First did you use the real SDK or the simulator?

The simulator SDK only hides some OS X calls that don't exist on iPhone, but is otherwise the normal OS X SDK. So first make sure you link against the (ARM) iPhone SDK.

Then comes the licensing bit. Afaik in a non jailbroken iPhone you can only load signed apps (via the AppStore, or using a license obtained from Apple to sign your own)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode will automatically install and run an application on your iphone if you use the correct project setting.

Project -> Set Active SDK -> iPhone Device 3.0

Note that you will need a provisioning key before this becomes possible.

visit http://developer.apple.com/iphone to view some easy-to-understand tutorials on how to get one of these.

I assume you have signed up as an iPhone developer on that website (costs $99).