# install iPhone application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, installation

i developed an application for iPhone.

i want to install my iPhone. how it is possible..

what is the procedure .

tnx and regards ..

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000721/is-it-possible-to-load-a-seperate-application-into-the-iphone

Answer (score 2):

I would assume you are already in the developer program and are able to run the program in the simulator.  The next step would be to provision your iPhone as a development device so you can install your apps on it.

You can find detailed instructions here:  [iPhone Development Guide: Managing Devices](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices/devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW2)

Answer (score 1):

You have to sign up for the Apple iPhone developer program and register for the $99 program to actually put it on the iPhone.

http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/program/apply.html