# How to create a application package in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I made a small application using XCode. How can i create a application package to install it in the iphone. can anyone help me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [install iPhone application in iPhone.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143068/install-iphone-application-in-iphone)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, as mentioned you will need to have paid the $99 developer fee.  Once you do that you can deploy through XCode directly to a device you have setup with a provisioning profile.  You can also deploy through iTunes (AdHoc Distribution).

Based on your responses to some of the other answers, perhaps this is the information you are looking for (Assuming you have or will have the developer account):

- Add a 512x512 png image of your Icon to your project and name it iTunesArtwork (no extension)
- Build your application with an Ad Hoc distribution provisioning profile being sure to include the UDIDs of ALL target devices (Instructions for this can be found within the iOS Provisioning Portal here: https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/distribution.action and https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action)
- Right-Click on your target in XCode and choose to *View in Finder*
- Create a new folder called *Payload*
- Copy your app into the Payload folder
- Right-Click on the Payload folder and choose *Compress*
- Rename the new zip file to YourApp.ipa (the ipa extension allows it to be picked up by iTunes directly.
- To distribute send both the .mobileprovision file (the Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile) and the .ipa file to your users
- Have them drag both files into iTunes to install them into their app library.  Then they can sync their devices as expected and now they have the app on an actual device.

More help can be found [here](http://www.innerfence.com/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution?zip_file=AppName.app.AdHoc.ipa).

Answer (score 3):

You have to pay the $99 fee to Apple to get a Developer account. With that account you'll be guided to install your app into a real iDevice.

Comment: Yep, and you need it to put it on your device. Unless it's jailbroken.

Comment: i need to create a package so that i can upload it to itunes

Comment: @Avinash: The **packaging** process (as you put it) is complicated, and the first step is to get a developer's account, which is called **provisioning portal** by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

To create an installation package of your App, mainly you need provisioning profile. This is for the authentication of the specific device. And that profile should consists the UDID of the specific device, in which you want to install that package(also called binary).

You will get that provisioning profile from a Apple Paid account. So you need to get a paid account(Developer account of cost $99) from Apple.

Regards,

Satya