# How do I register as a paid iOS developer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I developed an app. I want to test my app on my device. I am not registered with Apple.
How do I put identity to my device?
How do I run my app on my device?

Please give step by step instructions to run my app on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is "How do I register as a paid iOS developer", the answer is:
go to http://developer.apple.com and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 5):

The basic steps are as follows:

1) Signup for Apple's iOS Developer Program
2) Create a testing provisioning profile
3) Install provisioning profile to your test device
4) Run application on test device

The details of these steps can be found in Apple's documentation at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW9

Answer (score 3):

You **can't** run it on your device unless you are registered with Apple.

Since the question has been updated to ask about registering, please use [@Kris Babic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598547/kris-babic)'s answer. It's $99 (for a non enterprise account) and if you already have your app done or near done, it's worth it.

[@Kirs Babic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598547/kris-babic)'s answer (and some of the others) that indicate how to register should get you started.  Check out this question if you end up wanting to use Ad Hoc distribution (still requires Apple registration): [How to create a application package in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520166/how-to-create-a-application-package-in-iphone/4520514#4520514)

Answer (score 0):

Register as an iOS developer at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)