# How to save app on iphone?

Tags: iphone, deployment

If my iphone is plugged in, how do I save my app on it?

I have a developer account and certificates setup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [install iPhone application in iPhone.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143068/install-iphone-application-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

You need XCode to "install" your Application into the phone. Previously, you should have followed the steps to register your application, generate a provisioning profile for it, and a couple of other steps.

Check out Apple Documentation. It's pretty good with a lot of **step by step** tutorials on how to do that.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for the obvious link that i was looking for when this got posted.

Answer (score 0):

plug it in, click in the bar for device/simulator and choose device. if i'm right, you dont need to do anything else, just press build and go.