# ObjectFile problem

Tags: iphone

I have created sample application in iphone 2.0... Now i want to make this application as object files ...

How can i do this?

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you mean to ask how to install the application on a device?  If so, this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000721/is-it-possible-to-load-a-seperate-application-into-the-iphone

Answer (score 0):

See this SOQ [Can I develop my own objective-C Framework for Cocoa Touch Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300457)