# Rebuild a third party framework in Xcode

Tags: xcode, frameworks, air

I have a third party framework to connect a bluetooth device (Dice+) with an app, but I am building an ANE (Adobe Native Extension) to use the device in a AIR iOS aplication.

To build the ANE, I embed the framework, but AIR-iOS only works with ARMv7 architecture but  this framework is "universal" (ARMv6, ARMv7 and MAC OS).

There a way to repackage the framework from Xcode to be an ARMv7 architecture framework only?

Comment: Are you sure it's a framework rather than a library or bundle? You can't use third party frameworks on iOS.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I've used it and it works perfectly when I compile from Xcode, but I need to repack without the support ARMv6. And yes this is a third party frameworks on iOS

Answer (score 0):

Finally find the real solution:

- I unzipped the Framework file.
- Inside there are a file without extension and a folder named Headers
- Add the extension .a to the file without extension.
- Add the Headers folder and the file .a to the project.

Then just compile.

Indeed when trying to generate the IPA, got one ID64 error from Adobe AIR, now I can generate the IPA even in windows.

[Difference between framework and static library in xcode4, and how to call them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245761/difference-between-framework-and-static-library-in-xcode4-and-how-to-call-them)