# Create user library for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I am creating an 'SDK' which will enable communication with a piece of custom hardware (via BLE, abstracting my comm protocol to async methods/callbacks, on various classes all Obj-C). I wish to package this SDK so I can distribute it to users so they can build apps using this hardware. I want to provide an .h file(s) and a pre-compiled library (closed-source).

What's the best practice here? Shall I choose to create a .framework, .a, .dylib? 
what's the difference between them and their usage cases? what's the correct way to create the needed library?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot create dylib for iOS. User cannot link his project with that library dynamically on iOS, it is platform restrictions.
2. You can create framework or .a file (static library).
3. There can be some issues with resources from you library (framework)
4. It is dublicate question, see [Difference between framework and static library in xcode4, and how to call them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245761/difference-between-framework-and-static-library-in-xcode4-and-how-to-call-them)

Comment: what issues with resources from framework?
So should I go for .a or .framework?
couldn't find answers in the so-called duplicate question

Comment: This answer has been **deprecated** and should be updated after iOS 8 age.