# IOS static library for complex designs and architecture

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, swift, xcode6

I have create ticket form with certain fields and one table view controller to show list of all tickets.

When User clicks on any action Item (Like button, tab) it should call only one function like

```
[[Helpshift sharedInstance] showConversation:self withOptions:nil];
```

Now when this functions called list of all tickets should display. How I should call my table view controller inside showConversation method of helpshift class? Helpshift class is extended from NsObject class.

I want to distribute code like a static library just Like [helpshift](https://developers.helpshift.com/ios/sdk-configuration/). You can also watch video [here](https://developers.helpshift.com/ios/getting-started/#automated-integration)

This is what exactly I want to acheive.

Comment: U better use framework [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245761/difference-between-framework-and-static-library-in-xcode4-and-how-to-call-them)

Comment: checking with framework and its docs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include Xibs in your static library but you can make a folder that contain the static library myLib.a and a subfolder "header" that contain all the headers and the required Xib. you'll have to import all headers in your project. Maybe you can also create a .framework that would contain both but i'm not sure if you could access the xibs in the .framework

[image]