# Making an SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

I'm a bit confused about the semantics of an SDK, and how to make one for iOS. My understanding is that an SDK is essentially an API that implements all functionality necessary in building the thing it's for. I found a good explanation for the difference between API and SDK [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101873/whats-the-difference-between-an-api-and-an-sdk).

Now my question, though, is how do I create an "SDK" for iOS. Do I go into Xcode and create a new `Cocoa Touch Static Library` project? And what's the difference between that and `Cocoa Touch Framework`?

Should I follow this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial) to create my SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245761/difference-between-framework-and-static-library-in-xcode4-and-how-to-call-them). The term "SDK" generally refers to a possibly large collections of frameworks and libraries (as in "The iOS SDK").

Comment: I can't open the link

Comment: Hmm: try search in Stackoverflow using the terms library framework difference and Xcode