# Dependency management for COMPILED static libraries?

Tags: ios, xcode, dependency-management

I'm aware of Cocoapods. However this isn't very useful for commercial use because we don't want to deliver source code.

We want to be able to deliver compiled libraries. But use them in our own (and client) projects, just like with Cocoapods. And just like maven does with jar files and the suchlike.

Is there anything which provides this (or similar) functionality. It seems very shortsighted of Apple not to include anything like this, or the ability to support anything like this, within XCode.

Thanks

Comment: you can build frameworks and give them instead of your code. same as the jar files for java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300457/can-i-develop-my-own-objective-c-framework-for-cocoa-touch-applications have a lot of answers to this practise

Comment: Yes but then they have to be managed manually. This is what we're doing, but it would be great to set up a repo with compiled libraries with version numbers and automatic dependency management.

Comment: I haven't tried this - check out vendored_libraries in the podspec: http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html#vendored_libraries If cocoapods really support binary distribution, then we should enhance cocoapods!